# Filtering XML File using XPATH in Jasper Reports

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports

I am using Jasper Reports Studio, and I have two parameters

1. An XML Source file (see below) listing names of users and whether they are Active (`ACTIVE_USER`=1) or Non-Active (`ACTIVE_USER`=0)
2. An Input Source variable `Active_Selection` which is selected by the User. The three possibilities are "Non Active Users" (value=0), "Active Users" (value=1), "All Users" (value=2)

The XML File is as follows:

```
<ROOT>
<USER>
  <NAME>Patrick</NAME>
  <ACTIVE_USER>1</ACTIVE_USER>
</USER>
<USER>
  <NAME>Fred</NAME>
  <ACTIVE_USER>0</ACTIVE_USER>
</USER>
</ROOT>
```

I would like to filter my XML using xPath according to `Active_Selection`

The following code allows the User to select either Active or Non-Active users

```
<parameter name="Active_Selection" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/ROOT/USER[ACTIVE_USER=$P{Active_Selection}]]]>
    </queryString>
```

However, how can I allow the User to select either Active or Non-Active or All Users?

Answer (score 0):

This code works.

Note the use of parameters with default values to store interim calculations

```
<parameter name="MinActive" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[($P{Active_Selection}==0)?0:($P{Active_Selection}==1?1:0)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="MaxActive" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[($P{Active_Selection}==0)?0:($P{Active_Selection}==1?1:2)]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/ROOT/USER[ACTIVE_USER>=$P{MinActive} and ACTIVE_USER<=$P{MaxActive}]]]>
    </queryString>
```